# how do i fix the "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" error?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

trying to get a login system working with a mysql data base

this is my class for the database connection

```
package system.test.librarysystem;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DatabaseConnection {
    public Connection databaseLink;

    public Connection getConnection(){
        String databaseName = "sys";
        String databaseUser = "root";
        String databasePassword = "password";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + databaseName;

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            databaseLink = DriverManager.getConnection(url, databaseUser, databasePassword);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return databaseLink;
    }
}
```

and this is the login code i am then using the database connection

```
package system.test.librarysystem;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class LoginController {

    @FXML
    private Label loginLabel;
    @FXML
    private TextField usernameEntry;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordEntry;

    public void loginButtonAction(ActionEvent e) {
        if (usernameEntry.getText().isBlank() == false && passwordEntry.getText().isBlank() == false) {
            //loginLabel.setText("login successful");
            validateLogin();
        } else {
            loginLabel.setText("Please enter username and password");
        }
    }

    public void validateLogin() {
        DatabaseConnection connectNow = new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection connectDB = connectNow.getConnection();

        String verifyLogin = "SELECT count(1) FROM users WHERE username = '" + usernameEntry.getText() +  "' AND password = '" + passwordEntry.getText() + "'";

        try {

            Statement statement = connectDB.createStatement();
            ResultSet queryResult = statement.executeQuery(verifyLogin);

            while(queryResult.next()) {
                if (queryResult.getInt(1) ==1 ) {
                    loginLabel.setText("Welcome");

                } else {
                    loginLabel.setText("Invalid login");
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```

it keeps giving me the error **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver** i have added the connector file to my lib file and i have added it to dependencies and made sure my database was running but it still wont work, how can i fix this? (im using intellij and gradle)

Edit:
this is the build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'system.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.9.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = '19'
targetCompatibility = '19'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'system.test.librarysystem'
    mainClass = 'system.test.librarysystem.HelloApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = '19'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
```

Comment: what does "i have added the connector file to my lib file" mean? You need to add an entry to your gradle file.

Comment: Post the build config file (`build.gradle` if you are using Gradle). Is this a modular project? If so, post the `module-info.java` file; if not, post the VM arguments you are using.

Comment: I don't see you declaring a dependency on the MySQL JDBC driver in your build file.

Answer (score 0):

managed to fix this by going into my gradle.build file and using alt + insert to add the sql-connector as a dependency